How to read/write word from DECtape on SIMH?
I am learning programming assembly for PDP-4 using SINH simulator. I stuck at understanding how tape drives work. I want to read one word from DECtape 550 unit 1 but I don't know how. I'm learning PDP for the first time and I'm sorry. I looked at documentation and I found this example code:
jms MMWRS / MMRDS for Reading 
law 100 / LAC (100) Block Number 
jmp ERR / Error Return 
10000 / Unit Selection 
law 1000 / 1000, Core Starting Address 
law 1777 / 1777, Core Final Address

And I have found instructions for DECtape:

mmrd - READ, Clears (0 or AC and transfers one word from MMIOB to bits 0-17 of AC.
mmwr - WRITE. Transfers one word from bits 0-17 of AC to MMIOB.
mmse - SELECT, Connects the unit designated in bits 2-5 of AC to the DECtape Control.
mmlc - LOAD CONTROL. Sets the DECtape Control to the proper mode and direction from bits 12-17 of the AC, as follows:

12 - Go
13 - Reverse
14 - In-motion Read
15 - Modes:

0 - Move

1 - Search

2 - Read

3 - Write

4 - Spare

5 - Read through block ends

6 - Write through block ends

7 - Write timing and mark track

i. e. 42 = Read Forward

62 = Read Reverse

43 = Write Forward

41 = Search Forward

61 = Search Reverse

mmrs - READ STATUS. Clears the 10 or AC and transfers the DECtape status conditions into bits 0-8 of the AC as follows:

Bit 0 = Data Flag

Bit 1 = Block End Flag

Bit 2 = Error Flag

Bit 3 = Erid of Tape

Bit 4 = Timing Error

Bit 5 = Reverse

Bit 6 = Go

Bit 7 = Mark Track Error

Bit 8 = Tape Unable

mmdf - Skip on DECtape Data Flag. In Search Mode: Block mark number should be unloaded via mmrd instruction. In Read Mode: Data or Reverse Check Sum should be unloaded via mmrd instruction. In Write Mode: Data should be loaded via mmwr instruction.

mmbf - Skip on DECtape Block End Flag. In Read Mode: Unload forward Check Sum via mmrd instruction. In Write Mode: Load calculated forward Check Sum via mmwr instruction.

mmef - Skip on DECtape Error Flag. Timing Error, Mark Track Error, End Tape, or Tape Unable Condition has occurred. Use mmrs instruction to detect specific error.



Partial answer:
This here
jms MMWRS / MMRDS for Reading 

is a subroutine call, and that will only work if you have some operating system running on your simulated PDP-4 that actually provides those routines.
I don't know which documentation you used, and of course you didn't link to it, but when you look e.g. on Bitsavers, the DECtape 550 manual mentions

three types of program subroutines are furnished with, or can be obtained for use with, the DECtape system. The first is a basic set of subroutines for searching, reading, writing.

and

DEC-tape-subroutines, 4-45-IO are programs which allow the programmer to read, write and search the DECtape using prewritten and tested subroutines.

So you need those for your example code. And no, I don't know where to find those, but maybe the source for your example code has more info?
It's also not uncommon for DEC code to put parameters to a subroutine call after the call, so I'd guess that
law 100    / LAC (100) Block Number 
jmp ERR    / Error Return 
10000      / Unit Selection 
law 1000   / 1000, Core Starting Address 
law 1777   / 1777, Core Final Address

are parameters, some in the form of law opcodes.
Note that this will also read a complete block from DECtape into the specified core address, from the specified unit, jumping to the ERR label if anything went wrong.
It's not going to "read one word". Reading one word also doesn't make a lot of sense, as you have to find the right block etc.
Finally a suggestion: If you are learning PDP-4, it might make more sense to start with some code to read from keyboard or paper tape (if you have not already done so, but your question looks like you haven't).

If you want to write your own Operating System for the PDP-4, I suggest you do it as you would have done it when developing on a real PDP-4: Bootstrap from papertape, start with some kind of interpreter reading the keyboard. Then, add drivers.
That should also teach you how to use the IOT commands.
And the MMWRS / MMRDS routines would be extremely useful if you can find them somewhere, because you can basically copy them verbatim into your driver. Also keep in mind that the DECtape on simh is a simulation, not the real thing; code that works on simh may not work on a real PDP-4. Trying to do this all from scratch, with only a simulation as reference, and then working out all the kinks will be somewhat painful.
The simh website links to a zipfile with tapes for DECsys, potentially the routines are somewhere there in binary or even source form. DECsys is also interesting as an early-stage attempt on how to work with DECtapes.
If you are new to DECtapes, I also strongly suggest to try out OS/8 on a PDP-8, you can work really comfortable there. (I have done this on a real PDP-8 as well. BTW, the simulation is missing the timing aspect you have on real hardware. Tapes take time to rewind, and if your files are somehow down at the end of tape, you notice).

The tape routines for the PDP-7 are actually available here, you may have to modify them a bit for the PDP-4.

I found the example from this document: http://bitsavers.trailing-edge.com/pdf/dec/pdp7/F-75P_PDP7prelimUM_Dec64.pdf

The two paragraphs before the example code make it clear that the example is using DEC-supplied subroutines, which therefore need to be present in  your load image.

Oops, I just wanted to write a DECtape driver for my load image. So example code is irrelevant because I don't use an operating system for PDP.

The example code doesn't care about an operating system (there isn't one), but it does care about the DEC-supplied subroutines.  Since those subroutines are effectively a device driver, if your goal is to write a driver you presumably don't want them anyway.  You need to be coding at the IOT level. See p7-11 onwards.

I second the suggestion to start with something simpler than the 550 control. Printing "hello world" is (seriously) a good first exercise in device I/O. It'll probably impart a feeling for using the IOT instruction.

I only know  PDP-10 dectapes, and the controller might be very different from the 550 controller.  In the ten, DECtape was assigned two interrupt levels.  One for operting on entire blocks, and the other for transferring one word at a time.  The operating system would request a block read on one interrupt level, and the controller would generate an interrupt on the other channel each time a word was ready.

This Type 550 DECtape Control document appears to give the necessary information on how to control the DECtape from bare metal.
I've never programmed a PDP-4, PDP-7, or DECtape control, so you might want to take this with a pinch of salt. However...
The 550 is very low level. It can buffer one machine word. Meanwhile, the tape is reading and writing blocks. This means there are fairly tight timing requirements - you need to read words from the control as words appear, not before or after.
I would guess that you start an operation with mmlc, then loop reading the flags and issuing an mmrd when required.
